# Website does not load after SSL (Let's encrypt + Nginx)

Tags: nginx, debian

I just set up an SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt and when I change the port from 80 to 443 in nginx.conf. but after nginx restart, the website does not load and the browser gives me the **ERR_TIMED_OUT** error.

Nginx logs do not say anything and the config is correct. If I revert the config with port 80, the website works again.

My config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
root /var/www/html;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  domain.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_verify_client off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256 TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";

client_max_body_size 100M;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
}

 location ^~ /data {
     deny all;
  }
```

}

I never had this problem before.

I use a Debian 10 VPS and I'm setting up a mail server with postfix and dovecot.
How can I solve it? Thanks :)

Comment: Does `sudo nginx -t` report anything?

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Check if nginx is listening on port 443: `ss -ltn`. Check if firewall or other filter is blocking (either on the VPC itself or via whatever system it is hosted with).

Comment: Apparently, it does: https://pastebin.com/vRVT9n2z

Answer (score 1):

Try it without:

```
ssl_verify_client off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256 TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

My general go-to solution is commenting (using #) everything out that is not *required* for NGINX to work. I'm not saying that certain config variables should be disabled (tls 1.2 and 1.3 is a good choice for example), but it helps debug which **part** of your config is causing you troubles.

Another thing worth a try is removing http2 behind your listen directives and try if that works for you.